# last key value append new object list in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have doubt for nested last key value append new object list in javascript. My input is:

```
var list = [12,13,14,15]
```

I want output like:

```
list = [{first : 12,sec : 13},{first:13,sec:14},{first:14,sec:15}]
```

Comment: Learn what and how to ask questions on stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [How much effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the elements except the last and generate the object using current element and next element, use traditional for loop for iteration.

```js
let data = [12, 13, 14, 15]
let res = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++)
  res.push({ first: data[i], sec: data[i + 1] })

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map function to run over the list and return new list with the new data :

```js
var list = [12,13,14,15]
const newList = list.map(r=>({first:r,second:r+1})).slice(0, -1)
console.log(newList);
```

Comment: This works only for consecutive numbers. Won't work for `[1, 100, 200]`

Comment: @adiga whats the output you want to get from this `[1,100,200]` ?

Comment: This actually depends on how the question is interpreted (That' why I removed my downvote) Similar to how Pranav has answered: `[{first : 1,sec : 100},{ first:100,sec:200 }]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to aggregate results after modifying data as required.

```js
const data =  [12,13,14,15];
const res = data.reduce((res,num,index,all)=>{
  if(all.length > index+1) 
    res.push({first:num,sec:all[index+1]})
  return res;
},[])

console.log(res)
```